# ActiveModel::Serializer belongs_to attribute is not being displayed in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working but I have the following serializer:

```
class ExternalAccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :account_name, :type

  belongs_to :user, serializer: UserSerializer
end
```

The API is returning the following:

```
{
    "external_account":{
        "id":3,"account_name":"Company Inc.","type":"External service"
    }
}
```

The external account is being returned but the user is not. Any ideas why that is? How can I ensure this is displayed?

Comment: why is it like this, that `belongs_to` is not using serializer

Comment: It works for me as intended. Maybe they fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you must include :user on your attributes:

```
 attributes :id, :account_name, :type, :user
```

and then:

```
def user
  UserSerializer.new(object.user, root: false)
end
```

Comment: Only problem is that it then doesn't use the custom serializer

Comment: can you test my edition? I'm doing a similar thing with POROs, not sure if it works in your case @NickONeill

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: I had to include the user in the controller.

*posts_controller.rb*

```
  ...
  render json: post,
      include: 'user', # include user for custom serializer to work
   serializer: Api::V1::Post::PostSerializer,
       status: :created
```

Comment: docs: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option